# how to correctly bind data to radio buttons using angular reactive forms?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, radio-button, radio-group

I have struggled to do data biding to radio buttons using reactive forms.

My html file is as below

```
<form [formGroup]="newserviceform" (ngSubmit)="AddNewServices()" class="form" novalidate>
  <div class=" form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <p class="model-input-lables">Type(per)*:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" value=1 (focus)="focusNewServiceForm()" name="packagePriceOptionType"
          formControlName="packagePriceOptionType" checked>
        Event
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" value=2 (focus)="focusNewServiceForm()" name="packagePriceOptionType"
          formControlName="packagePriceOptionType">
        Person
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="radio-icon" type="radio" value=3 (focus)="focusNewServiceForm()" name="packagePriceOptionType"
          formControlName="packagePriceOptionType">
        Item
      </label>
      <div
        *ngIf="packagePriceOptionType.errors && ((packagePriceOptionType.dirty && packagePriceOptionType.touched)||isformsubited)">
        <p class="form-error-messege" *ngIf="packagePriceOptionType.errors.required">Price option is required</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="packagePriceOptionType.value!=1" class=" form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <p class="model-input-lables">Quntity*:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <!-- onkeydown is an inbuilt function to trigger an instatant key press 
    here it reduce taking the value of e and - in a key press -->
      <input (focus)="focusNewServiceForm()" type="number" min="200" class="form-control input-popup"
        formControlName="packageItemQuntity" (keyup)="numericOnly($event)"
        onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69 && event.keyCode !== 189"
        onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
      <div
        *ngIf="packageItemQuntity.errors && ((packageItemQuntity.dirty && packageItemQuntity.touched)||isformsubited)">
        <p class="form-error-messege" *ngIf="packageItemQuntity.errors.forbiddenValueValidator">Invalid value</p>
        <p class="form-error-messege" *ngIf="packageItemQuntity.errors.required">Quntity is required</p>
        <p class="form-error-messege" *ngIf="packageItemQuntity.errors.min">Minimum quantity is 200 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

my `ts` file is as below. I am setting the initial value of the radio button to `1`. But it does not bind.
But I saw that this can be done by using template driven forms. But here i need to do this using reactive forms

```
  newserviceform: FormGroup;
  packagePriceOptionType: FormControl;
  packageItemQuntity: FormControl;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createNewServiceForm();
  }

  createNewServiceForm() {
    this.createNewServiceFormControls();
    this.newserviceform = new FormGroup({
      packagePriceOptionType: this.packagePriceOptionType,
      packageItemQuntity: this.packageItemQuntity,
    });
  }

  createNewServiceFormControls() {
    this.packagePriceOptionType = new FormControl(1, [Validators.required]);
    this.packageItemQuntity = new FormControl(1, [
      Validators.min(1),
      this.forbiddenValueValidator(/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/),
    ]);
  }
```

Do anyone have an idea where is the issue? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please rectify your template(HTML). The value property is not quotted properly in HTML.

Comment: okay rectified!

Comment: @CharukaHerath, Can you try changing  ```value``` to ```[value]``` (including square brackets around value)??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I tried just now. But it did not work. Thanks!!

Comment: @CharukaHerath, Can you reproduce your issue in this stackblitz where the radio button groups are working state https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-buttons-reactive-forms-mfuz1p

Comment: @ManirajMurugan seems like it works fine in this one. Bur for some reason it does not work in my machine..

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and the issue is in assigning value attribute in template. When you are writing `value="1"`, it assign value of `string` "1" to value attribute. But you are using `number` data type in reactive form.

If you want it to work perfectly use string type in your component class like done below:

```
this.packageItemQuntity = new FormControl('1', [
      Validators.min(1),
      this.forbiddenValueValidator(/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/),
    ]);
```

Please find the working **stackblitz** here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynziux

Answer (score 0):

Somehow even if we provide numeric value to the value parameter in the input radio element, it is processed as strings. You can this instead(eg. [value]=1), works like a charm.
eg.

```
<input class="radio-icon" type="radio" [value=1] (focus)="focusNewServiceForm()" name="packagePriceOptionType" formControlName="packagePriceOptionType" checked>
```